# Clip UWP TextBlock as it moves out of its container

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm attempting to build an odometer like effect in UWP where when a number is incremented it slides up and dissappears while the incremented number appears by sliding up from the bottom (in a very similar mannor to how the [Odometer JS library](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/) works).

I have the number contained in a text block, that is animating properly.

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                               Storyboard.TargetName="Digit1">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-80" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Currently, when the number moves up it is still completely visible.  I want the `TextBlock` to be "clipped" to its containing `Canvas` so that it progressively dissappears as it moves outside the bounds of the `Canvas`.

I have tried both clipping the `TextBlock` to the `Canvas` and visa versa, neither of which had the desired effect.

```
<Canvas x:Name="Odometer"
        Clip="{Binding Clip, ElementName=Digit1}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Digit1"
               FontSize="100"
               Text="8"
               Canvas.Left="-104"
               Canvas.Top="-30"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
               Clip="{Binding Clip, ElementName=Odometer}">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform> <CompositeTransform /> </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```

I do not need to use a `Canvas`, it's just what I was playing around with.  I'm still very new to UWP, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to [UIElement.Clip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> The clipping geometry for UIElement.Clip in the Windows Runtime API must be a [RectangleGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.rectanglegeometry.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So, if you want to give a outline for `canvas`, you need to specify a `RectangleGeometry` for your `canvas.clip`, which take a rect of your canvas's actual size.

You can achieve this progrmmatically:

```
private void Odometer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RectangleGeometry rectangle = new RectangleGeometry();
    rectangle.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, Odometer.ActualWidth, Odometer.ActualHeight);
    Odometer.Clip = rectangle;
}
```

And don't forget to remove the clip in xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Odometer" Loaded="Odometer_Loaded">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Digit1"
           FontSize="100"
           Text="8"
           Canvas.Left="104"
           Canvas.Top="10"
           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform />
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```